# Coldfusion CFHTTP.Responseheader

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am going nuts trying to figure out how to read the content of the `cfhttp.responseHeader`.  I am trying to access a website which sends a couple of cookies in the response. I need to extract them from the response. Then send the cookie values with all future requests. I tried to use below code:

```
<cfloop collection = #cfhttp.responseHeader# item = "httpHeader">
  <cfset value = cfhttp.responseHeader[httpHeader]>
    <cfif IsSimpleValue(value)>
      <cfoutput>
      #httpHeader# : #value#<BR>
      </cfoutput>
<cfelse>
      <cfloop index = "counter" from = 1 to = #ArrayLen(value)#>
       <cfoutput>
        #httpHeader# : #value[counter]#<BR> 
       </cfoutput>
 </cfloop>
</cfif>
```

But that throws the following error

```
Object of type class coldfusion.util.FastHashtable cannot be used as an array  


The error occurred in C:/inetpub/wwwroot/cfdocs/Response.cfm: line 22

20 :     </cfoutput>
21 :   <cfelse>
22 :     <cfloop index = "counter" from = 1 to = #ArrayLen(value)#>
23 :       <cfoutput>
24 :         #httpHeader# : #value[counter]#<BR>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve the cookies like this:

```
<cfset cookies = cfhttp.responseHeader["set-cookie"] />

<cfdump var="#cookies#" />
```

You can then use that cookie struct data to make your subsequent requests.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to loop over a structure but treating it as an array. You need to use "collection" to loop over structures.

```
<cfloop collection="#cfhttp.responseHeader['set-cookie']#" item="sKey">
    .....
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script I made to get the header cookies using a reference on the Ben Nadel website.

```
public struct function GetResponseCookies(required struct Response){
    var LOCAL = {};
    LOCAL.Cookies = {};

    if(!StructKeyExists(ARGUMENTS.Response.ResponseHeader,"Set-Cookie")){
        return LOCAL.Cookies;
    }

    LOCAL.ReturnedCookies = ARGUMENTS.Response.ResponseHeader[ "Set-Cookie" ];

    if(!isStruct(LOCAL.ReturnedCookies)){
        return LOCAL.Cookies;
    }

    for(LOCAL.CookieIndex in LOCAL.ReturnedCookies){
        LOCAL.CookieString = LOCAL.ReturnedCookies[ LOCAL.CookieIndex ];

        for(LOCAL.Index =1; Local.Index != ListLen( LOCAL.CookieString, ';' ); LOCAL.Index++){
            LOCAL.Pair = ListGetAt(LOCAL.CookieString,LOCAL.Index,";");
            LOCAL.Name = ListFirst( LOCAL.Pair, "=" );

            if(ListLen( LOCAL.Pair, "=" ) > 1){
                LOCAL.Value = ListRest( LOCAL.Pair, "=" );
            } else {
                LOCAL.Value = "";
            }

            if(LOCAL.Index EQ 1){
                LOCAL.Cookies[ LOCAL.Name ] = {};
                LOCAL.Cookie = LOCAL.Cookies[ LOCAL.Name ];
                LOCAL.Cookie.Value = LOCAL.Value;
                LOCAL.Cookie.Attributes = {};
            } else {
                LOCAL.Cookie.Attributes[ LOCAL.Name ] = LOCAL.Value;
            }
        }
    }
    return LOCAL.Cookies;   
}
```